# Toggle element if its bottom reaches screen´s top

Tags: jquery, html

I want toggle an element if the top of the screen reaches the bottom of that element. The thing is my function does not work and I do not know how to solve this, I really searched for a long time on the internet but could not find anything unfortunately. Could you please help me 
I used to toggle it like that:

```
$(".tablee").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

jQuery (my try to toggle if element´s bottom reached screen´s top):

```
if (($(".hiddenpost").offset().bottom + $(".hiddenpost").height()) <= $(window).height()) {
    $(this).slideToggle();
}
```

HTML (reduced to the important things):

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="tablee" style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="hiddenpost"  style="height:400px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="tablee" style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="hiddenpost"  style="height:400px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="tablee" style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="hiddenpost"  style="height:400px;"></div>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To start, you are using a class as your selector. When you have multiples of this class in the DOM, you will run into a problem.

Try either specify a specific instance of the class, or run your method on all classes.

Below, in my untested example, when I scroll, I check each .hiddenpost to see if it is in the desired position.

You can try something like this:

```
<Script>
  $(function(){
    $("body").on("scroll",function(){
      $(".hiddenpost").each(function(){
        var x = $(this);
        if ((x.offset().bottom + x.height()) <= $(window).height()) {
          x.slideToggle();
        }
      });
   });
});

</script>
```

Comment: I understand what you did there but it still doesn't work... thanks for the answer though, that looks much better than mine